# Path helper changing "/search?option=..." to "/search.option=..." when anchor is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a seemingly simple case with Rails' path helpers. My route is straightforward:

```
get 'search', to: 'search#search_results'

$ rails routes
...
search GET    /search(.:format)                     search#search_results
```

I need to inject an `option=graph` parameter into the query string on the current page. This works as expected:

```
<%= link_to "Graphs", search_path(request.query_parameters.merge({:option => "graphs"})) %>
```

Giving a link like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?body=&commit=Search&feedback=&option=graphs&reason=&site=&title=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&username=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&why=foo
```

However, when I specify the `anchor` parameter, something weird happens:

```
search_path(request.query_parameters.merge({:option => "graphs"}), anchor: "graph-1")
```

```
http://localhost:3000/search.body=&commit=Search&feedback=&option=graphs&reason=&site=&title=&user_rep_direction=%253E%253D&user_reputation=0&username=&utf8=%25E2%259C%2593&why=foo#graph-1
```

The anchor is added as expected, but the `?` to start the query string turns into a `.` - which irritates the controller because it's an unrecognized format.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Running Rails 5 beta 4 on Ruby 2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing it turns out that you should **include the anchor when merging the params**:

```
search_path(request.query_parameters.to_h.merge({option: "graphs", anchor: "graph-1")})
```

**Explanation:** your approach, i.e.:

```
search_path(request.query_parameters.merge({:option => "graphs"}), anchor: "graph-1")
```

actually passes **two separate hashes** as arguments to the `search_path` helper instead of just one. However, in the [helper definition code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.rc1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L284), only **the last hash** argument is taken as the real options parameter to the helper. Other arguments are processed differently.

In the end, the `anchor` argument gets understood by the helper as the *format* specifier (I found this out by debugging the path construction in the helper but am unable to point to a precise place in the source code) and that is why the resulting path contains a dot `.` after the resource name.

**Update:** Note, that the `query_parameters` must also be converted to a hash, as normally they are of the `ActionController::Parameters` and are also processed differently in the path helper. After unifying all params and the anchor to a `Hash` class, the path should be correct.